# Error in updating edmx file

Tags: c#

I am getting an error when I am updating the edmx file.

> Error 3002: Problem in Mapping Fragment starting at line 3828:
>   Potential runtime violation of table  Archive's keys (Archive.UserID):
>   Columns (Archive.UserID)  are mapped to EntitySet Archive's properties
>   (Archive.UserID)  on the conceptual side but they do not form the
>   EntitySet's key properties  (Archive.ListID, Archive.UserID).

Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Check the mapping between the two tables. It sounds like the properties are mapped to the wrong field.

Take a look at: http://cticoder.wordpress.com/2008/10/14/entity-framework-error-3002-error-3003/